# Audio does not stop when I put the app in the background on android with flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am developing an app in flutter and there are several times when I need to play audio.
When audio is playing, the audio does not stop even if I put the app in the background. i have tried with audioplayers and just_audio, both with the same result.
It would be easiest if it could be controlled by android config files etc., or is there a way to control AudioPlayer globally in one of the packages?
I will also include the current code. Thank you.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AudioPlayer.global
      .setAudioContext(AudioContextConfig(respectSilence: true).build());

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // play audio
    final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    audioPlayer.setSourceAsset("audio/home.mp3").then((_) {
      audioPlayer.setVolume(0.1);
      audioPlayer.resume();
    });
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can try using pause() by detecting manually that app went in background.